# Formal solutions of Laplace equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve a Laplace equation in polar coordinates:

> \begin{equation} u_{rr}+\dfrac{1}{r}u_{r}+\dfrac{1}{r^{2}}u_{\theta\theta}=0, 0\le r<a\\u_{r}(a,\theta)+\alpha u(a,\theta)=f(\theta), \alpha>0 
>  \end{equation}
>   where $f$ is a $2\pi$ periodic continuous function.

My attempt: Using the separation of variables method $u(r, \theta)=R(r)\Theta(\theta)$ we have $\dfrac{\Theta''}{\Theta}=\dfrac{-r^{2}R''}{R}-\dfrac{rR'}{R}=-\lambda$ is a constant. The boundary condition now is $[R'(a)+\alpha R(a)]\Theta(\theta)=f(\theta)$. If $R'(a)+\alpha R(a)\neq 0$ then $\Theta(0)=\Theta(2\pi)$ and we have a differential equation:

> \begin{matrix}\Theta''+\lambda\Theta=0\\\Theta(0)=\Theta(2\pi) \end{matrix}

However, it seems like this boundary condition is not enough to solve this equation. For example, when $\lambda=\beta^{2}>0$ the general solution is $\Theta(\theta)=C\cos{\beta \theta}+D\sin{\beta\theta}$, so how can we find $C, D$ and $\beta$? And what if If $R'(a)+\alpha R(a)=0$? Now I'm stuck, can anyone help?

Moreover, this exercise requires to find reasonable conditions on $f$ so that the formal solution is a solution. I don't understand what does it mean and how can I solve this.

Comment: For $f(\theta)$ use the Fourier representation. And the $R'(a)+\alpha R(a)=0$ case cannot be satisfied given your boundary condition

Answer (score 2):

First, the angular function. The periodic condition required $\beta = n$, where $n=0,1,2,\dots$ where $n$ is an integer.

$$ \Theta_n(\theta) = \begin{cases} C_0, & n = 0 \\ C_n\cos(n\theta) + D_n\sin(n\theta), & n > 0 \end{cases} $$

Plugging the eigenvalue into the radial equation, we have
$$ r^2R'' + rR' - n^2 R = 0 $$

This has a general solution:

$$ R_n(r) = \begin{cases} A_0 + B_0\ln r, & n = 0 \\ A_nr^n + B_nr^{-n} , & n > 0 \end{cases} $$

Since $R(0)$ needs to be finite, we can reduce some of the constants

$$ R_n(r) = \begin{cases} A_0, & n = 0 \\ A_nr^n, & n > 0 \end{cases} $$

Hence

$$ u_n(r,\theta) = \begin{cases} A_0C_0 , & n = 0 \\ A_nr^n\big(C_n\cos(n\theta) + D_n\sin(n\theta)\big), & n > 0 \end{cases} $$

Using the law of superposition, we find:

$$ u(r,\theta) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nu_n(r,\theta) = c_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty r^n\big(c_n\cos(n\theta) + d_n\sin(n\theta)\big) $$

where I've combined several constants into one.

---

**Finally**, we can now plug in the boundary condition

$$ u_r(a,\theta) + \alpha u(a,\theta) = f(\theta) = \alpha c_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \big(a^{n-1}+\alpha a^n \big)\big(c_n\cos(n\theta) + d_n\sin(n\theta)\big) $$

To find the remaining constants, compute the Fourier series of $f(\theta)$

\begin{align}
\alpha c_0 &= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(\theta) d\theta \\
\big(a^{n-1}+\alpha a^n \big)c_n &= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} f(\theta)\cos(n\theta)\ d\theta \\
\big(a^{n-1}+\alpha a^n \big)d_n &= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} f(\theta)\sin(n\theta)\ d\theta
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have done it by myself in the same way. But now how can I find the condition on $f$ such that the formal solution is a solution? Does it mean that the Fourier series of $f$ converges to $f$?

Comment: In general, any periodic continuous function will have a converging Fourier series.